# angularjs 1.2 - validation directive update on $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have the following directive that I'm using for validation on a multi-select to allow for (dynamic) length validation of the number of selected items.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myModule')
        .directive('listLength', listLength);

    listLength.$inject = ['$parse'];

    function listLength($parse) {
        var directive = {
            require: 'ngModel',
            restrict: 'A',
            link: link
        };

        function link(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
            var length = 0;
            var exp = $parse(attr.listLength);
            if (exp.constant) {
                // Single value, no need to watch
                length = exp(scope);
            } else {
                // We have an expression, need to watch for changes
                scope.$watch(attr.listLength, function(newVal, oldVal) {
                    length = newVal;
                });
            }

            //For DOM -> model validation
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
                if (!angular.isUndefined(value) && value !== "") {
                    var valid = value.length === length;
                    ngModel.$setValidity('listLength', valid);
                    return valid ? value : undefined;
                }
                return value;
            });

            //For model -> DOM validation
            ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function(value) {
                if (!angular.isUndefined(value) && value !== "") {
                    var valid = value.length === length;
                    ngModel.$setValidity('listLength', valid);
                }
                return value;
            });
        }

        return directive;
    }
})();
```

In order to have it update properly, I need to trigger the validation to be run when the expression (attr.listLength) updates, but it's not obvious to me how to achieve this. I tried setting `ngModel.$dirty` to true but it still does not update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only way to do this in Angular 1.2 is to use `ngModel.$setViewValue`, which triggers all the validation functions. So if I do

```
scope.$watch(attr.listLength, function(newVal, oldVal) {
    length = newVal;
    ngModel.$setViewValue(ngModel.$viewValue);  // Set view value to itself...
});
```

It then triggers the validation functions. In angularjs 1.3+ this can be done with ngModel.$validate()

Answer (score 0):

Try change the watch parameter like that:

```
scope.$watch("listLength", function(newVal, oldVal) {
       length = newVal;
});
```

Comment: This stops it working entirely :) The $watch function itself was working fine, but when length is updated I need to re-validated the $parsers.unshift value against the new length

Comment: I believe that validation should be called in watch callback. On watch callback, the only code that is executed is the set value to the attribute.